# Share Sheet Crashing on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I'm creating a share sheet where someone can share the text from a text field. I've got it working on the iPhone, but the app crashes on the iPad. I know that it has to be in a popover form and have had this issue back in the day of Objective-C, but I can't seem to figure it out on Swift. This is my code that I've got going for the share sheet:

```
@IBAction func myShareButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Hide the keyboard
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        // Check and see if the text field is empty
        if (textView.text == "") {
            // The text field is empty so display an Alert
            displayAlert("Warning", message: "You haven't written anything yet!")
        } else {
            // We have contents so display the share sheet
            displayShareSheet(textView.text!)
        }
    }
    // Show Warning
    func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
    // Display Share Sheet
    func displayShareSheet(shareContent:String) {
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareContent as NSString], applicationActivities: nil)
        presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {})

    }
```

Comment: Update your question with the error and point out where it crashes. You should also search on the error before posting your question. It's probably been answered before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented share sheets today as well and had the exact same issue. You need to add this before presenting.

```
if let popoverPresentationController = activityController.popoverPresentationController {
     popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
     popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: CGRectGetMidX(view.bounds), y: CGRectGetMidY(view.bounds), width: 0, height: 0)
     popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.init(rawValue: 0) //Removes arrow as I dont want it
}
```

Line 1 sets the source view.

Line 2 I use to Center the popover right in the middle (I use it in SpriteKit and the popover is not attached to anything)

Line 3 I use to remove the arrow as I don't want it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Don't forget to add an IF to the beginning of the "UIDevice.current..." statement since it contains a binary operator

Comment: Surely `activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.init(rawValue: 0) //.Down` should just be `activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .down`

Comment: Using 0 removes the arrow completely which I prefer when the UIActivityController is not attached to anything.

Comment: Checking the userInterfaceIdiom is not a reliable way to do this.

Comment: He, thx for the comment. What else do you suggest? Why would it not be reliable, still seems to be the best API to check the current device. It even got added to macOS Catalyist.

Comment: hey, I updated my answer. Just checking for the optional popoverPresentationController should do right?

Answer (score 1):

**for Swift 3/4**
Depends on @crashoverride777 Answer

```
if let popoverPresentationController = activityVC.popoverPresentationController {
     popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view
     popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
     popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.init(rawValue: 0) //Removes arrow as I dont want it
}
```